# Is it ok to ask a question about just one software?

Tags: discussion

Have a look to this question: [Software for Software Designing like Visio / Rational Rose](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/915/software-for-software-designing-like-visio-rational-rose)

The guy could explain me about IrfanView. I want to get some extra detail about this software, and I can do it by opening a question like: "What do you think about IrfanView?"

Do you think is good to do it?

(I really think it is a good idea)

Comment: "But I need to open a question to go deep about it." seems awfully unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by "But I need to open a question to go deep about it." this is unclear to me...

Comment: ps: in which way downvoting improves the quality of this SE section? It seems to me to be an addiction..

Comment: Also see my answer to [What kind of software reccomentations is this section for?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/449/185).

Answer (score 3):

This site is for software *recommendations*. If you need help with a specific application, this is the wrong place to ask. For many things, you will find a specialized SE site; but even in case there's none, SR still is not the place for this.